# Number of lines of code in RAD/Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, rad

How do I find number of lines of code in `RAD` or `Eclipse` in entire workspace
(all the projects)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- add a plugin like [Eclipse metrics](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/example/index.html)
- create a project which **depends on all the other projects** in the workspace
  (Java Build Path, tab "`Projects`", for adding "`Required projects on the build path`")
  Don't bother with the compilation: even if that global project doesn't compile it will give you the information you need.

[image: Java Build Path]

- display the [project summary metric](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/example/Project.1.html):

[image: Summary stats]

Comment: VonC, I gave this method a shot and it didn't fully work. I was able to export metrics for a global project I made (with every other project on its build path) but the exported HTML has no data - e.g., 0 packages, 0 classes, 0 TLOC. Any ideas? These are J2EE projects so I'm wondering if that could be the cause.

Comment: @Bears: strange, I didn't test it recently but it may have missed the right directories to analyze in your case.

Comment: I would like to get lines of code by language, for ex: java - 123 lines of code, html - 8383 lines of code.. etc.. is there any tool for it?

Comment: @Naren that could be a question in itself. In fact, it probably already is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104756/how-do-you-count-your-lines-of-code